# docker compose unable to find installed python

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a web app runs on ubuntu containers, the root `docker-compose.yml` as below:

```
services:
    api: 
        volumes:
            - ./api/:/var/www
    vue: ...
```

I use `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python` in the `Dockerfile` under `api` directory to install python inside the `api` service.
The `docker-compose up` runs successfully.

However, I have no idea how to run python inside this `api` service. The console logs `python` command is not found.

I tried to login onto `api` container using `docker-compose exec api /bin/bash` and exe `find / -type d -name "python"` but I got

```
find: '/etc/ssl/private': Permission denied
find: '/root': Permission denied
/usr/share/gcc-6/python
find: '/proc/tty/driver': Permission denied
find: '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial': Permission denied
find: '/var/cache/apt/archives/partial': Permission denied
find: '/var/cache/ldconfig': Permission denied
```

My `api` service has two subservices as its `docker-compose.yml` shows:

```
services:
   web:
       links:
           - app
       volumes:
           - ./:/var/www
   app: ...
```

So how can I use python in my `api` service? Or how I know python is installed correctly?

==============

**Update:**

`Dockerfile` in `api` service:

```
FROM php:7.1.27-fpm

# Set to keep file permissions same as host for mounted volume
RUN useradd -m -u 1000 ubuntu

# Install GD
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libfontconfig1 libxrender1 git zip mysql-client && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd \
          --enable-gd-native-ttf \
          --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 \
          --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install MySQL
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

# Install Other Dependencies
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install exif

# Install Composer
RUN apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    composer self-update && \
    apt-get remove --purge curl -y && \
    apt-get clean

# Configure PHP
RUN echo "php_admin_flag[log_errors] = On">>/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf

# Install Xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.9.8 && \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

WORKDIR /var/www

# Install python
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python
```

And `docker-compose.yml` in `api`:

```
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: web.docker
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        links:
            - app
        volumes:
          - ./:/var/www
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
```

Comment: It would help if you included your dockerfile as well as the docker compose file. It could be a setting in there that is causing the issue.

Comment: @allan please check updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the permission denied error because you defined a non root user. If you want to check if python is installed, you can just check from the command prompt inside the container via `python --version`.
You should include the python command in your docker file to start up the api so this will get started when you run docker-compose up, such as

```
CMD ["python", "<path to python api script>.py"]
```